# ArgumentOutOfRangeException and I can't figure out why

Tags: powershell, ado, ms-access-2013

I'm building a PowerShell script that retrieves some info stored in a MS Access 2013 database file. The query is being built dynamically from some other data collected on the machine. I went for a full modular approach and put all of the database functions and management in a separate module that I am bringing in with a "Using Module" statement (the functionality is to be rather large, so I thought this would make it easier to manage the code). Everything appears to be working well except for the `openRecordSet` function.

Here is the constructor for my Database class as well as my `connectToDatabase` method and `openRecordSet` method:

```
Database($dbPath) {
    $this.connectToDatabase($dbPath)
}

connectToDatabase($Db) {
    $this.databasePath = $Db
    $this.connection = New-Object -ComObject ADODB.Connection
    $this.connection.Open("Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='$Db'")
    if ($this.connection -eq $NULL -OR $this.connection.State -eq $this.adStateClosed) {
        throw "$this.DatabasePath found but a valid connection could not be made."
    }
}

[object] openRecordSet($query, $cursorType, $lockType) {
    $RecordSet = New-Object -ComObject ADODB.Recordset
    Write-Host "query = $query"
    return $RecordSet.Open($query, $this.connection, $cursorType, $lockType)
}
```

This is the code giving me problems. It is in another class that has successfully created a database object and connection by the time execution reaches this line:

```
$RecSet = $this.database.openRecordSet($query, 3, 1)
```

Using Visual Studio Code's debug mode, a `Write-Host` statement and running it in MS Access, I have confirmed that the SQL statement inside `$query` is proper. The second parameter is the cursor type, which is Dynamic in this instance, and the third parameter is the lock type, which is ReadOnly in this instance. I was using constants I had defined in the Database class but changed them to  primitive numeric values to confirm that those weren't causing the problem. The error did not change. Here is the error message:

```
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the
collection.
Parameter name: index
At C:\Users\FakeUser\Documents\MySuperScript\modules\userprofiles.psm1:20 char:21
+ ...                  $RecSet = $this.database.openRecordSet($query, 3, 1)
+                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], ArgumentOutOfRangeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException
```

I can't figure out what is causing this error. `$query` is a string and `$this.connection` is a comObject Connection. I've used this same syntax in a different script with no issues, it was only when I started playing with modules that this happened. Surely it's a simple syntax problem or some other easy thing I'm overlooking.

Comment: What is the value, length, and index of `$query` when it errors?

Comment: `$query = SELECT * FROM [Tbl_Users] WHERE [USERNAME] = "john.doe"`
 The length is: 61
 I'm not sure what you're referring to by "index", it is just a plain string, not an array or hashtable.

Comment: Can you post the actual line that fills the $query variable? I'm sure you just typed it above from memory but it's not looking correct, so I'd like to see the actual line

Comment: The above was copy and pasted from the console (it is the output of the `Write-Host` statement in the first code block), although I added the $ to the left side to indicate it was the variable. Here is the actual line of code copy and pasted from the editor: `$query = "SELECT * FROM [Tbl_Users] WHERE [USERNAME] = \`"$val\`""`

Comment: Also, I just double checked and confirmed that `$val` is indeed a plain text String, not an array or hashtable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return type of the `Open` method is void. The error pops up because you are casting void to object in order to return it.
Here is a listing of ADODB.Recordset

```
_xClone():ADODB.Recordset (Method)
_xResync(AffectRecords:ADODB.AffectEnum):System.Void (Method)
_xSave(FileName:System.String, PersistFormat:ADODB.PersistFormatEnum):System.Void (Method)
AbsolutePage:ADODB.PositionEnum (Get Property)
AbsolutePage:System.Void (Set Property)
AbsolutePosition:ADODB.PositionEnum (Get Property)
AbsolutePosition:System.Void (Set Property)
ActiveCommand:System.Object (Get Property)
ActiveConnection:System.Object (Get Property)
ActiveConnection:System.Void (Set Property)
AddNew(FieldList:System.Object, Values:System.Object):System.Void (Method)
BOF:System.Boolean (Get Property)
Bookmark:System.Object (Get Property)
Bookmark:System.Void (Set Property)
CacheSize:System.Int32 (Get Property)
CacheSize:System.Void (Set Property)
Cancel():System.Void (Method)
CancelBatch(AffectRecords:ADODB.AffectEnum):System.Void (Method)
CancelUpdate():System.Void (Method)
Clone(LockType:ADODB.LockTypeEnum):ADODB.Recordset (Method)
Close():System.Void (Method)
Collect:System.Object (Get Property)
Collect:System.Void (Set Property)
CompareBookmarks(Bookmark1:System.Object, Bookmark2:System.Object):ADODB.CompareEnum (Method)
CursorLocation:ADODB.CursorLocationEnum (Get Property)
CursorLocation:System.Void (Set Property)
CursorType:ADODB.CursorTypeEnum (Get Property)
CursorType:System.Void (Set Property)
DataMember:System.String (Get Property)
DataMember:System.Void (Set Property)
DataSource:System.Object (Get Property)
DataSource:System.Void (Set Property)
Delete(AffectRecords:ADODB.AffectEnum):System.Void (Method)
EditMode:ADODB.EditModeEnum (Get Property)
EOF:System.Boolean (Get Property)
Fields:ADODB.Fields (Get Property)
Filter:System.Object (Get Property)
Filter:System.Void (Set Property)
Find(Criteria:System.String, SkipRecords:System.Int32, SearchDirection:ADODB.SearchDirectionEnum, Start:System.Object):System.Void (Method)
GetRows(Rows:System.Int32, Start:System.Object, Fields:System.Object):System.Object (Method)
GetString(StringFormat:ADODB.StringFormatEnum, NumRows:System.Int32, ColumnDelimeter:System.String, RowDelimeter:System.String, NullExpr:System.String):System.String (Method)
Index:System.String (Get Property)
Index:System.Void (Set Property)
let_ActiveConnection(pvar:System.Object):System.Void (Method)
let_Source(pvSource:System.String):System.Void (Method)
LockType:ADODB.LockTypeEnum (Get Property)
LockType:System.Void (Set Property)
MarshalOptions:ADODB.MarshalOptionsEnum (Get Property)
MarshalOptions:System.Void (Set Property)
MaxRecords:System.Int32 (Get Property)
MaxRecords:System.Void (Set Property)
Move(NumRecords:System.Int32, Start:System.Object):System.Void (Method)
MoveFirst():System.Void (Method)
MoveLast():System.Void (Method)
MoveNext():System.Void (Method)
MovePrevious():System.Void (Method)
NextRecordset(RecordsAffected:System.Object&):ADODB.Recordset (Method)
Open(Source:System.Object, ActiveConnection:System.Object, CursorType:ADODB.CursorTypeEnum, LockType:ADODB.LockTypeEnum, Options:System.Int32):System.Void (Method)
PageCount:System.Int32 (Get Property)
PageSize:System.Int32 (Get Property)
PageSize:System.Void (Set Property)
Properties:ADODB.Properties (Get Property)
RecordCount:System.Int32 (Get Property)
Requery(Options:System.Int32):System.Void (Method)
Resync(AffectRecords:ADODB.AffectEnum, ResyncValues:ADODB.ResyncEnum):System.Void (Method)
Save(Destination:System.Object, PersistFormat:ADODB.PersistFormatEnum):System.Void (Method)
Seek(KeyValues:System.Object, SeekOption:ADODB.SeekEnum):System.Void (Method)
Sort:System.String (Get Property)
Sort:System.Void (Set Property)
Source:System.Object (Get Property)
Source:System.Void (Set Property)
State:System.Int32 (Get Property)
Status:System.Int32 (Get Property)
StayInSync:System.Boolean (Get Property)
StayInSync:System.Void (Set Property)
Supports(CursorOptions:ADODB.CursorOptionEnum):System.Boolean (Method)
Update(Fields:System.Object, Values:System.Object):System.Void (Method)
UpdateBatch(AffectRecords:ADODB.AffectEnum):System.Void (Method)
```

Slightly modified example using your code:

```
Class Database  {
    [string] $databasePath
    $connection
    $adStateClosed

    Database($dbPath){
          $this.connectToDatabase($dbPath)
    }

    connectToDatabase($Db){
        $this.databasePath = $Db
        $this.connection = New-Object -ComObject ADODB.Connection
        $this.connection.Open("Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='$Db'" )
        if($this.connection -eq $NULL -OR $this.connection.State -eq $this.adStateClosed){
            Throw "$this.DatabasePath found but a valid connection could not be made."
        }
    }
    [object] openRecordSet([string] $query, $cursorType, $lockType){
        $RecordSet = new-object -ComObject ADODB.Recordset
        $RecordSet.Open($query, $this.connection, $cursorType, $lockType)
        return $RecordSet
    }
}


$db = [Database]::new("C:\MonthlySalesReport\MonthlySalesReports.accdb")
$query = "SELECT 1 AS CONNECTED"
$result = $db.openRecordSet($query, 3, 1)

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $result.RecordCount; $i++) {
    $record = $result[$i]
    Write-Host ($record.Name + " " + $record.Value)
}
```